# What is the difference between net.connect and net.createConnection in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I was reading the documentation from the net module in Node.js and I can't see any difference between the methods `net.connect` and `net.createConnection`.

Are they exactly the same or is there is some difference?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's no difference. Here's an extract from the [source code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/net.js):

```
exports.connect = exports.createConnection = function() {
```

I agree the documentation isn't clear on that point.

Comment: Now the better question: why did they create a synonym yet provide different documentation for each?

Answer (score 2):

The are exactly the same, just a different name, form the sourced code

> net.createConnection() creates a net.Socket object and immediately
>   calls net.Socket.connect() on it.

And also from the source code on line [62](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/net.js#L62) of the Net module.

```
exports.connect = exports.createConnection = function() {
  stuff
};
```

Why they did this, I don't know. Just pick the naming convention that you prefer and off you go :)